# Zend Service Amazon - Internal Server Error - Works on localhost?

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework, internal-server-error

I am having a really frustrating problem with my Zend Service Amazon package integrated into my codeigniter framework. The library works perfectly fine in my localhost but when I try it from the live site it doesn't work, it gives me an internal server error. Why could this be?

The error in the PHP log is:

> [22-Nov-2012 21:29:02] PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home5/tradejun/public_html/application/controllers/dev.php on line 30
>   [22-Nov-2012 21:29:02] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home5/tradejun/public_html/application/controllers/dev.php on line 30

Line 30:

```
$autoloader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array(
```

Here is my controller function:

```
public function amazon2($isbn)    {
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'application/libraries/Amazon');
    require_once 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';

    $autoloader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array(
        'namespaces' => array(
            'Zend'        => dirname(__FILE__) . '/Zend',
            'ZendRest'    => dirname(__FILE__) . '/ZendRest',
            'ZendService' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/ZendService',
        ),
        'fallback_autoloader' => true));

    $autoloader->register();

    $tag       = 'colleg-21'; // replace with your Amazon app ID
    $appId     = '[appid]'; // replace w/ your access key from https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials
    $secretKey = '[secretkey]';
    $query  = new ZendService\Amazon\Query($appId, 'UK', $secretKey);
    $item   = $query->itemLookup($isbn,
        array('SearchIndex'   => 'Books',
            'AssociateTag'  => $tag,
            'IdType'        => 'ISBN',
            'ResponseGroup' => 'Large',));
    $item->smallImageAddress = $item->SmallImage->Url->getImageAddress();
    $item->mediumImageAddress = $item->MediumImage->Url->getImageAddress();
    $item->largeImageAddress = $item->LargeImage->Url->getImageAddress();
    $data['item'] = $item;
    $this->load->view('development/amazon',$data);
}
```

Can anyone provide any suggestions or possible solutions?

Points

- Works perfectly fine on localhost, but not on live host server
- I am using ZendService_Amazon-2.0.2.zip
- CodeIgniter version is 2.02

Comment: What is an error message? Did you check log?

Comment: @E_p I've posted a link to the error message in the question. What log should I check? Sorry I'm a bit of a noob at this.

Comment: It does not show an error. As display errors is turned off. Your web server error log should contain actual error of what have happened. If you have access to your php.ini switch `display_errors On` to see an error. Do not forget to switch it off after

Comment: OK thanks didn't realise, I've updated the question now with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be an old version of php - doesn't support namespaces. You need php 5.3 for namespaces. You'll need to upgrade.

Edit: corrected version number required for namespaces; only need 5.3, not 5.4. Thanks, E_p

Comment: Thanks guys. Is there any way I can modify the code to get around this in the meantime? - nevermind, upgrading was easier than I thought. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry. It is 5.3 for namespaces. Glad you could upgrade as 5.2 has been end of life for a little while.